# What kernel modules are necessary for using a standard USB 2.0 flashdrive

Tags: kernel-modules, usb-drive, buildroot, modprobe

I am using buildroot to generate an Image to run linux on an Arm A53.  I want to be able to shut off and turn on the ability to see a USB flashdrive on command.  I went into the settings of buildroot and modularized the device drivers for USB.  When I boot up I cannot see the USB that is plugged in, which is fine; but I have `modprobe`'d almost every kernel module that was generated for the USB drivers and no matter what I can still never see the flashdrive.  What .ko file is necessary to `modprobe` in order to see this flashdrive?

**NOTE:** I could see, use, and mount the flashdrive when I was using the Image that had the USB device drivers built into the kernel.  I didn't add or subtract any of the options in buildroot when I modularized the USB device drivers and that was the only change that I made to any of the settings in buildroot before running `make`.

Answer (score 1):

`usb_storage.ko` and its dependencies.

Comment: Yeah I used `modprobe` and it also loaded `usbcore`, but it still doesn't work.  Do you know if there are additional dependencies?